# Using SweetAlert to Display messages after inserting data to MySql using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have combined html, php and ajax to insert data in mysql database. And I want to display success or error messages in ajax success function using SweetAlert. The data is getting inserted into the database but I am unable to display the messages. 
Following is my code:

insert.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
$db = mysql_select_db("hotelmanagement", $connection);

$fName = $_POST['fName'];
$lName = $_POST['lName'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$phone =  $_POST['phone'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$checkInDate =  $_POST['checkInDate'];
$checkOutDate =  $_POST['checkOutDate'];
$adults =  $_POST['adults'];
$children =  $_POST['children'];
$specialInstructions =  $_POST['specialInstructions'];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation(FirstName,LastName,Address1,Address2,Phone,Email,Adults,Children,CheckInDate,CheckOutDate,SpecialInstructions) VALUES('$fName','$lName','$address1','$address2','$phone','$email','$checkInDate','$checkOutDate','$adults','$children','$specialInstructions')");

echo json_encode($query);

mysql_close($connection);
```

?>

And this is my ajax code:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var fName = $("#fName").val();
    var lName = $("#lName").val();
    var address1 = $("#address1").val();
    var address2 = $("#address2").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var checkInDate = $("#checkinDate").val();
    var checkOutDate = $("#checkoutDate").val();
    var adults = $("#adults").val();
    var children = $("#children").val();
    var specialInstructions = $("#specialInstructions").val();


    if(fName == '' || lName == '' || phone == ''){
        swal("Oops!!", "Looks like you missed some fields. Please check and try again!", "error");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'insert.php',
            data: {fName:fName,lName:lName,address1:address1,address2:address2,phone:phone,email:email,checkInDate:checkInDate,checkOutDate:checkOutDate,adults:adults,children:children,specialInstructions:specialInstructions},
            dataType:'json',
            succcess:function(data){
                swal("Success", "Data Saved Successfully", "success");
            },
            error:function(xhr, thrownError, ajaxOptions){

            },
        });
    }
});
```

Could you please tell me what am I missing. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you echo'ing your query result -> `echo json_encode($query)`?

Comment: Do have errors in developers console?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez Its all the same. Whether I echo or not the alert is not displaying. And there are no errors in developers console. The data is inserted into mysql. And when I check Networks in browser, the preview is showing "true"

Comment: @IndraGotamey you should `echo mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: @PathikVejani I tried you code. Still no SweetAlert. But thanks.

Comment: you have a comma `},` after error: function(){} **,**

Comment: console `data` and see what happens

Comment: @PathikVejani Nothing. Its still not working. Seems like its not getting into the success function at all. De we need to return something from php? If yes then how to do it?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez Removed that comma. Still no difference.

Comment: what comes in `data`?

Comment: @PathikVejani I dont know. When I do alert(JSON.stringify(data)) nothing happens. Form data is posted correctly and insert operation is successful. But I just cant alert the success message in ajax success function.

Comment: your success callback is triple `ccc` and try to remove `dataType:'json',` see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your success callback is triple `ccc` and try to remove `dataType:'json',`

try this ajax request

```
$.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'insert.php',
            data: {fName:fName,lName:lName,address1:address1,address2:address2,phone:phone,email:email,checkInDate:checkInDate,checkOutDate:checkOutDate,adults:adults,children:children,specialInstructions:specialInstructions},

            success:function(data){
                swal("Success", "Data Saved Successfully", "success");
            },
            error:function(xhr, thrownError, ajaxOptions){

            }
       });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That spelling mistake in the sucess function has been the problem the whole time. Thank you so much. It worked. Now Sweet alert is working ....sweetly